# Is it possible to install Shibboleth SP on its own server?

Tags: apache, iis, shibboleth

Is it possible to install the Shibboleth Service Provider (SP) on a different machine than the web application? I have the SP on the same server as IIS and my web application, and I'd like to move the SP to a separate server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After take a look how to separate SP server from Web Server.

I found this [link](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPOneMany).

According to this site, we have to create the glue ourselves
Shibboleth doesn't do this for us.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see any relation between your question and answer.
The answer is **YES**, you can install Shibboleth SP on something other than IIS

general installation notes

- [Apache for windows](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPWindowsApacheInstaller) (I believe that you need something for that OS)
- [All Windows installations](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPWindowsInstall) (including IIS 5,6,7 and Apache)
- [All Linux tutorials](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPLinuxInstall) (look for your system in subpages)
- [Mac](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPMacInstall)
- [Install Shibboleth to protect Java Servlets](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPJavaInstall)

Hope that will help any other knowledge seeker.

Comment: may be my english is not good and that leads to my question is misinterpreted. My application is deployed on IIS. Right now, I install SP service on the same machine as IIS and run on its own service but what I want to ask is "Can we deploy SP elsewhere other than the same machine as I deploy My application and IIS"